# customizing environments in Google cloud shell

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I want to customize Google cloud shell, so I made some changes to these files:

```
$HOME/.customize_environment
/etc/profile.d/init_help.sh
/google/devshell/bashrc.google
```

but when I restart the shell, only the first file keeps it's changes, but the other two files reset to their original content (may be because there are outside of $HOME dir).

how can I make a perminant change to these files?

Comment: Only changes made to $HOME are persisted.

Comment: this is what I said in the issue description, and the question is: how can I customize the other files? @JohnHanley

Comment: You cannot change other files and have them persisted. Cloud Shell is a container. Any changes you make are discarded when the container is shut down or restarted except for $SHOME.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish anyway? Anything in the system-wide config files can be overridden in your personal shell configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct on your guess when you say that other files not located at `$HOME` resets when the shell restarts. As discussed in the comments, only files located at `$HOME` can be modified **and persisted** between sessions. It is well documented in [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell):

> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as your $HOME directory. **All files you store in your home directory**, including installed software, scripts and user configuration files like .bashrc and .vimrc, **persist between sessions**. Since your .bashrc persists across sessions, it's a great way to customize your Cloud Shell behavior. Similarly, you can install packages into your home directory to have your installations persist.